# view intercepts touch before it takes window

Tags: ios, animation, touch

Hello in my app i emulated slide view's and use this code

```
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

unfortunately new view intercepts touch before it takes window : if i make double click,with second click work new view
I check frame of this view it equal frame of window

if i turn off animation it  work correct. but i need animation effects

Please help me to find right decision )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using blocks for the `UIView` animation. Initially disable the touch on the new view. Then animate and in completion block, enable the touch.

```
//disable touch on the slide view
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                            //.. animate here
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                            //enable touch on the new view
                         }]
```

Comment: Thank you it's work,but fast))) now i will try to research this problem)

Comment: Play with the animateWithDuration property. Change it's value to something high and try. It should slow down.

Comment: i dont know why but it work right when i insert this 
 [UIView   setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
before my code

Comment: There are other methods such as animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:. check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html for more details.